# SQL Vlookup/join

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

As i'm new to sql i find it difficult to explain my problem but i ll give it my best.
I want to join 2 tables but i got a number of conditions that i have to apply to get the result i want.

Table 1 contains part code and the manufacturing price (CurrFrozenCostPrice):[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olmNi.png)

Table 2 contains part code, starting date, ending date, minimal quatity and a sales price:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxKBz.png)

I want the sales price from table 2 added to table 1 with the following conditions:
I only want the sales price from the record with the highest amount in column MinQty and where todays date is between the startdate and enddate. If there is no record that matches these conditions than i want it to return 0 as outcome. I added table 3 as an expamle for the result i am looking for.
[Example result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbjbh.png)

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). It would be better if you provide the tables and data as code formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you're pulling the SQL tables into Excel, and then you're looking to pull some information off of that.  What you're going to want to do is create a conditional array that uses some nested if statements to create that output.  Take a look at Example 2 on this site - https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/03/04/excel-array-formula-examples/

Hopefully that will get you going on the right track.  If you're still hitting a roadblock with the implementation after that, come back with an update to your question showing what you've tried and we'll take another look at it.  Good luck!